# Harmonic forms from a variational perspective?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, harmonic-functions

**In short:** Are harmonic forms critical points of some generalized Dirichlet functional?

Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold, denote by $\Omega^k(M)$ the space of $k$-valued forms on $M$. Let $d:\Omega^k(M) \to \Omega^{k+1}(M),\delta:\Omega^{k+1}(M) \to \Omega^k(M)$ be the exterior derivative and its adjoint, respectively.

A $k$-form $\sigma$ on $M$ is called harmonic if $d\sigma=\delta \sigma=0$ (or equivalently if $\Delta \sigma=0$ where $\Delta=d\delta +\delta d$).

$0$-harmonic forms (also known as harmonic functions) are critical points of the Dirichlet integral: $E(\sigma)=\int_M |d\sigma|_{g}^2 \operatorname{Vol}_g$. Is there an analogous variational realization for forms of higher degree?

(Perhaps $E(\sigma)=\int_M |d\sigma|_{g}^2 + |\delta \sigma|_{g}^2 \operatorname{Vol}_g$ is the right choice?)

Also, what about vector-valued forms?

Any reference for a variational treatment would be appreciated.

Comment: This very much related to something that has been bothering me for a long time. There's the bochner formula which says $\Delta = \nabla^*\nabla + C$ for some linear operator $C$ depending only on the curvature of the connection of the metric. Using the hermitian metric on compactly supported differential forms induced by integration we get $(\Delta \omega , \omega) = ||\nabla \omega||^2 + (C \omega, \omega) $. For a long time I've been suspecting that this might be a hamiltonian for a classical field theory whose solutions are harmonic differential forms.

Comment: The case of harmonic functions is probably known to you already and there $C$ is just $0$ and the action is just $||\nabla\phi||^2 = \int_M |\nabla \phi|^2 dVol$ so the theory i'm looking for should restrict to this one. Perhaps the lagrangian density is really just $|\nabla \omega \wedge * \nabla \omega + C\omega \wedge * \omega)$ for this $C$

Comment: So have you had any progress since 2016 regarding this? What i meant in the lagrangian was $L(\omega,\nabla \omega) = \nabla \omega \wedge *\nabla \omega - C\omega \wedge *\omega$ (i have no idea what the sign should be and in any case it depends on $C$).

Comment: I am not sure about your suggestions. (I am not very familiar with either the Bochner formula, or with classical field theory). However, the solution to the problem of finding a variational characterization of harmonic forms is relatively simple. You can see my newly added answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $M$ is closed.

Define

$$ E:\Omega^k(M) \to \mathbb{R} \, \, \,, \, \, \,E(\sigma)=\frac{1}{2}\int_M |d\sigma|^2 + |\delta \sigma|^2 \operatorname{Vol}_M.$$

Let $\sigma \in \Omega^k(M)$, and let $\sigma_t$ be a smooth perturbation of $\sigma$, i.e. $\sigma_0=\sigma$. Denote $V:=\frac{\partial \sigma_t}{\partial t}|_{t=0} \in  \Omega^k(M)$.

Then,

$$\frac{d}{dt} E(\sigma_t)=\int_M \langle d\sigma_t, \frac{\partial}{\partial t} d\sigma_t  \rangle  + \langle \delta \sigma_t,  \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\delta \sigma_t \rangle \operatorname{Vol}_M.$$

Now, we note* that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} d\sigma_t=d\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \sigma_t$, so in particular $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} d\sigma_t|_{t=0}=d(\frac{\partial \sigma_t}{\partial t}|_{t=0})=dV$.

Similarly, we have $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \delta\sigma_t|_{t=0}=\delta(\frac{\partial \sigma_t}{\partial t}|_{t=0})=\delta V$.

This implies

$$\frac{d}{dt} E(\sigma_t)|_{t=0}=\int_M \langle d\sigma, dV  \rangle  + \langle \delta \sigma,\delta V \rangle \operatorname{Vol}_M=\int_M \langle \delta d\sigma, V  \rangle  + \langle d\delta \sigma, V \rangle \operatorname{Vol}_M$$

$$ =\int_M \langle \delta d\sigma+d\delta \sigma, V  \rangle  \operatorname{Vol}_M=\int_M \langle \Delta\sigma, V  \rangle  \operatorname{Vol}_M.$$

So, the Euler-Lagrange equation of $E$ is exactly $\Delta\sigma=0$, hence the critical points are precisely the harmonic forms.

The same proof carries through to the setting of vector-valued forms.

---

*The equality $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} d\sigma_t=d\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \sigma_t$ is immediate from the coordinate expression for $d$, and the fact that $\sigma_t$ is a smooth family.